Android 14 USB Tethering RNDIS not working
The Killer 1650i Wi-Fi card in my Dell G5 5511 laptop died on me recently and I need to use my smartphone as a Wi-Fi adapter for a substitute without having to order a replacement Wi-Fi card. My phone I'm using is an LG V20 running unofficial Android 14 (LineageOS 21).
Trying to switch it on while connected to my computer just turns it off immediately (as seen if backing out of the Tethering settings), but the notification and Quick Settings tile still reads that USB tethering is on. Reading the logcat for diagnosing this problem there is this:
Tethering: ERROR could not enable IpServer for function RNDIS
It's the error message with NO Google Search results. In fact that's such an undocumented error right there!
Wi-Fi and Bluetooth tethering work fine. But with the Wi-Fi card dead or disconnected that means I can't use Bluetooth as another way to connect to my computer unless I have a USB adapter for a substitute of it.
How the heck do I fix this?
